# Simple push server for prototyping

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, reactjs-flux, prototyping

I want to make a live prototype to demonstrate transactions between two users in different browsers. It should keep the state of the UI in sync between two sessions when each user performs an action. For instance: when one user presses purchase in one browser window, the other user should see that the item is marked as sold in another.

There's nothing new about this, except that I need the absolute minimum solution to fake this behaviour in order to be able to iterate quickly to optimize the flow before starting the actual implementation.

I was thinking Flux and React, or maybe node, but I'm completely new to these frameworks.

Does anyone here have a good suggestion to the best way of approaching this without ending up building a full application? Or maybe to direct me to good starting points?

Comment: The react tutorial covers this behaviour with a demonstration of a simple chat room.

Comment: Pub/sub over web socket via http://crossbar.io should be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen the chat examples, and they do cover a lot of the functionality.

Comment: Crossbar.io looks really interesting. I'll take a good look at it now.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is a NodeJS-ExpressJS-SocketIO combination solution.

It might sound scary if you don't have experience with any of those, but SocketIO is one of the libraries I usually describe as magic.

Just look at the example of the SocketIO website (which already includes everything to run) [example instructions](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and [the code of the example](https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example)

I never used react so I can't say anything on how simple it is to do using it. but the big magic here is actually SocketIO. it might be usable inside react.

Comment: Again, if you want to spend as little time on building a full application and just do your mock, this is makes things so easy :-)